# How can i access value of datalist controls which generated at run time in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

The datalist generated code at runtime: how can I access values of the datalist element after page postback?

```
void CreateDATELIST(Control container)
{   
    var st = settings.CustomPossition();
    foreach (var item in settings.CustomPossition())
    {  
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Possition");
        dt.Columns.Add("Production");
        dt.Columns.Add("dpo");
        dt.Columns.Add("WorkDay");
        DataRow dr;
        foreach (var users in item.Users)
        {
            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Name"] = users.Name;
            dr["Possition"] = users.Position.Name;
            dr["Production"] = users.DailyGoalAmount * (double)(users.WorkDays / 12;
            dr["dpo"] = users.DailyGoalAmount;
            dr["WorkDay"] = users.WorkDays;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            dt.AcceptChanges();
        }
        DataList dataList = new DataList();
        dataList.ItemTemplate = Page.LoadTemplate("Commnets.ascx");
        container.Controls.Add(dataList);

        dataList.DataSource = dt;
        dataList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: please give me any suggestion..

Comment: From where you call CreateDATELIST function?

Answer (score 0):

If you assign `Id` to your `DataList` created dynamically like following:

```
DataList dataList = new DataList();
dataList.ID = "dlstUser";
```

And then: change control ID in `c.FindControl("lblName")` with whatever control & ID you have in your template user control and use following code in button click or in whatever event where you want values of your `datalist`.

```
DataList dataList = pnlDataList.FindControl("dlstUser") as DataList;
foreach (DataListItem dli in dataList.Items)
{
    ControlCollection controls = dli.Controls;
    foreach (Control c in controls)
    {
        Label lblName = c.FindControl("lblName") as Label;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just subscribe to DataList's **ItemDataBound** event.

```
DataList dataList = new DataList();
dataList.ItemDataBound += dataList_ItemDataBound;
```

and in event handler:

```
void dataList_ItemDataBound(object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
{
      var item = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView;
}
```